# Azure scheduler mechanism to send email as ErrorAction

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler

I want to send an email as an ErrorAction. As per Micorsoft documentation, Azure schedulers provide a mechanism to send user notifications as part of error Action. Please let me know of any pointers of how this feature can be used.